# How can I schedule an sqlite query to be run after a timer finishes?

Tags: android, sqlite, timer, chronometer

I'm trying to make an sqlite query run after a timer finishes every time, e.g every 24 hours I want to insert some data into the database?

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` and `JobScheduler`

Answer (score 1):

Countdown timer has a callback method when the timer is getting over.

In your case it is better to schedule alarm manager that triggers your operation every 24 hours.